# Ruby on Rails after decode showing some unicode char

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the API I have sent one encrypt code like this:

```
irb(main):051:0> Base64.encode64("12wwwe344,ABCD")
"MTJ3d3dlMzQ0LEFCQ0Q=\n"
```

Now I am sending it to the Rails API through header key: `"MTJ3d3dlMzQ0LEFCQ0Q=\n"`

But in rails server console I got:

```
↕??Y??♣ ]
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The message is encoded to " ↕??Y??♣ ] " .
 After receiving it we should decode it .

```js
2.3.0 :001 > Base64.encode64("12wwwe344,ABCD")
 => "MTJ3d3dlMzQ0LEFCQ0Q=\n" 
2.3.0 :002 >  Base64.decode64( "MTJ3d3dlMzQ0LEFCQ0Q=\n" )
 => "12wwwe344,ABCD"
```

thanks 
rate it